# ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I'm using Active Model Serializers v0.10.0.rc4

I want to produce json that looks like this:

```
{
  "posts": [
    { "post": {"id": 2, "name": "foo"} },
    { "post": {"id": 3, "name": "bar"} }
  ],
  "next_page": 3
}
```

I know the basic:

```
render json: posts, each_serializer: PostSerializer
```

will produce json like this:

```
[
  {"id": 2, "name": "foo"}
  {"id": 3, "name": "bar"}
]
```

I have attempted the following:

controller:

```
render json: posts, serializer: PostsSerializer
```

posts_serializer:

```
class PostsSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :posts, :next_page

  def posts
    ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer.new(object,
      each_serializer: PostSerializer,
      root: "post"
    )
  end

  def next_page
    3 
  end
end
```

But this produces json like this:

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "object": {"id": 2, "name": "foo"},
      "instance_options": {"each_serializer: {}", "root": "post" }
    },
    {
      "object": {"id": 3, "name": "bar"},
      "instance_options": {"each_serializer: {}", "root": "post" }
    },
  ],
  "next_page": 3
}
```

Anyone know how I can achieve the desired schema?

Comment: I'm currently working on this same issue. Please let me know if you figure this out.

Answer (score 3):

In the end I didn't use `CollectionSerializer`. This is what I went with instead:

controller:

```
render json: posts, serializer: PostsSerializer
```

posts_serializer:

```
class PostsSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :posts, :next_page

  def posts
    object.map do |p|
      ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(p, adapter: :json)
    end
  end

  def next_page
    # todo
  end
end
```

Specifying the `json` adapter ensured that the `post` elements had the required root node.

Whilst I appreciate that having a root node specified for array items may not be conventional, it was required for this api.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON result you need is similar to that specified in the [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/format/) format. To achieve this with `active_model_serializers`, you'll need to use the `JsonApi` adapter. You can specify this in the initializer file:

```
ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json_api
```